# $R^iF(M)=0$ for $i>\dim A$ where $F$ is left exact functor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring s.t. the Krull dimension $\dim A<\infty$,
$M$ be a $A$-module, and $F$ be left (resp. right) exact functor.

Now for $i>\dim A$, the right derived functor $R^iF(M)=0$ (resp. $L_iF(M)=0$)?

When $A$ is PID, this is true because a $A$-module is injective iff divisible (resp. submodule of free module is also free).

If necessary, we may assume $A$ is Noetherian, domain, and so on.

Comment: You may want to think of results relating the global dimension of $A$ with its Krull dimension. For this, $A$ probably does need to be "nice enough".